# Css transition fixed width vs max-width

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I have 2 examples. First one has fixed width to 400px and expands with transition, second one has max-width and does not expand with transtion. But if I check offsetWidth before transtion, they both return 400.

How can I make second one expand with transition?

```js
document.getElementById('t').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(document.querySelector('.plan').offsetWidth)
  document.querySelector('.plan').classList.add('expanded')
})

document.getElementById('t2').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(document.querySelector('.plan').offsetWidth)
  document.querySelector('.plan2').classList.add('expanded')
})
```

```css
.plan {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: width 0.3s ease-out, height 0.3s ease-out;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.plan2 {
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: width 0.3s ease-out, height 0.3s ease-out;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.expanded {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="plan"></div>

<a href="#" id="t">expand</a>

<div class="plan2"></div>

<a href="#" id="t2">expand 2</a>
```

Comment: max-width: 100% (like you did with width)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `max-width: 100%` instead of `none` for the `.expanded` class:

```js
document.getElementById('t').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(document.querySelector('.plan').offsetWidth)
  document.querySelector('.plan').classList.add('expanded')
})

document.getElementById('t2').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(document.querySelector('.plan').offsetWidth)
  document.querySelector('.plan2').classList.add('expanded')
})
```

```css
.plan {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: width 0.3s ease-out, height 0.3s ease-out;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.plan2 {
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: max-width 0.3s ease-out, height 0.3s ease-out;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.expanded {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="plan"></div>

<a href="#" id="t">expand</a>

<div class="plan2"></div>

<a href="#" id="t2">expand 2</a>
```